# Use incoming caller ID on Twilio to make outgoing call

Tags: twilio

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

Caller rings Twilio number which gets answered and then automated message is played.
Caller is placed in a queue
In parallel to this, our system dials a number (using the rest API) *showing the caller id of the incoming call*, plays a gather to verify the user wants to pick up, and then connects the call.

I know that the easiest way to achieve something similar to this is to redirect the incoming call with a Dial verb, but for reasons that aren't really relevant to the question that isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yes, this is possible, with the caveat that the initial callers phone number must be previously verified with Twilio.  See this topic in the help center:

http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-i-use-a-non-twilio-number-as-the-caller-id-for-outgoing-calls

Hope that helps.

Devin

Comment: Hi Devin, Unfortunately that isn't the case. Should have probably mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Keep in mind that, depending on the experience you want to give your customers, you can use the Twilio API to have them verify their number.  This works well if you are providing a service that they will be using multiple times.  Your app simply has them verify their number the first time they use your service, then you can use it as a caller ID.

Comment: Hi Devin, thanks for your time with this. I think what I'm trying to do isn't possible. The summary (and I've got an issue open with support investigating it) is that when we forward calls sometimes the caller doesn't hear a ringing. Because of that I want to try and make the calls using REST and then link them. However I still want the callee to get the caller ID of the caller.

Comment: OK, sounds like the ideal resolution is solving the ring issue.  Hopefully our support team can get get that solved for you.

Comment: I ran into this same problem, and a host of other problems, when I was trying to make a queue that calls the agent, rather than the other way around. If anyone here can help the thread is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420812/how-do-i-get-twilio-to-call-the-agent-to-connect-them-to-callers-in-the-queue

Comment: @matthew-steeples This issue of the caller not hearing ringing (they just hear silence) is without doubt one of my most frustrating issues with twilio at the moment. Has anyone found a way to resolve it? Twilio customer service suggested I use their twimlet - which doesn't really solve the caller id problem - not very helpful....

Comment: @user714852 No unfortunately the closest we could get to resolving it is that it depends on the particular carrier that Twilio use for that particular call. We've modified our system so that a message pops up on the user's screen with the calling number, and the number that appears on their phone as it rings is our own.

Comment: That's a pretty cool hack - it's a shame its necessary. I'm having quite a lot of dropped calls due to this silence issue. It's a shame we can't connect the caller to a ringing recording while the other end answers.